# Using a color from a dataframe as the color of a line for seaborn's pointplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I currently have a large `pandas` dataframe which has columns which I have structured as:

```
Groups  variable  value  method  color
```

I then use **`pointplot`** to create a multiple `lineplot` with each line as a different color. Originally I used `hue` to do this over the `method` values, however I end up having to create a few of these dataframes, each with a different order in how I put the method in (because I sort over one method, then make that chunk of data the first entries into the dataframe, and do this for several different methods). I want each method to be associated with only one color, so that it is consistent across all of the `pointplots` that I make. So, I created a new column called `color` which holds the RGB value that I want to be associated to that method. I come across some issues, however, when I try to plot this:

```
g = sns.pointplot(x="Groups",jitter=0.3,alpha=0.7,size=15,y="value", color=result1['color'],data=result1[result1['variable']=="Accuracy"])
```

This causes a **`TypeError`**, though, as **Series objects are mutable, thus cannot be hashed**. Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: From my initial understanding, the issue is with the color argument,
it expects a single string/code value  for color. use the hue keyword argument instead to color your plot according to a different categorical variable.

Comment: Like I said, I can't use "hue". I need the group to be mapped to a specific color.

Comment: I think the palette argument should work then

Comment: Your chances of obtaining a satisfying answer will increase dramatically when providing a [mcve] of the issue, together with the result, a clear explanation what is wrong with it and how it should look like instead. I'm sure there is a solution to any such problem, but at the moment the question does not even allow me to judge on whether a possible solution would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use palette, instead of color if you are specifying multiple colors from [Seaborn Docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html)

```
g = sns.pointplot(x="Groups",jitter=0.3,alpha=0.7,size=15,y="value", palette=result1['color'],data=result1[result1['variable']=="Accuracy"])
```

Comment: Doing this seems to have resulted in only one of my Groups being plotted, and being plotted incorrectly (the line no longer connects from point to point, but rather there are vertical lines scattered throughout the graph) but thank you for the palette insight, I'll look more into that as I don't think color is correct